# Create Uplift in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I want to create a uplift in excel pivot table using a calculation. Just wondering if there is a way to do this. Could not find a workable solution so far. Here is what I am looking for, =IFERROR(AVERAGE(K3:M3)/AVERAGE(B3:J3)-1,0); column A to S is from the pivot table.
[image]

For the comment part as follows,
=IF(S3<=5,"-",IF(AND(SUM(G3:L3>5,M3=0),"OK"),"Not OK","OK"))

I want to do the above calculation when there are more rows added or delete some rows without updating the column T & U. Just wanted that to be part of the pivot table

Comment: I've read your question several times, but I still do not understand what or why you are asking for help.

Comment: I want to do the above calculation when there are more rows added or delete some rows without updating the column T & U. Just wanted that to be part of the pivot table.

Comment: So you copied the pivot table data and paste it here and use that for calculation? That would never update if data would get added. Why are you not adding a calculated column to the pivot table itself? Or if you really want it to update live, you need a formula solution, not pivot table. So please explain yourself further.

Comment: Yes this is copied data to explain my question (So column A to S is actual pivot table that exist) as I cannot show the actual pivot table due to data privacy. The part I could not do was adding calculated column to pivot table. That was the part I was having trouble with.